# Why I got KeyError in loop "for" with regular expressions?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I got pandas.Series with few values.

```
money = pd.Series(df_t['Сокращенное наименование '].unique())

0    USDCNY_TOM
1    USDRCNY_TOD
dtype: object
```

My regular expression:

```
m_trim = re.compile(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')
```

When I run this code, it's works.

```
m_trim.sub('', money[0])
```

Result is: `'USDCNY'`.

But then I trying to make loop:

```
for m in money:
    money[m] = m_trim.sub('', money[m])
```

I get KeyError: `'USDCNY_TOM'`.

Thay am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for m in money` is looping over the **values** of the Series. Thus `money[m]` is incorrectly trying to use the values as indices.

Use:

```
money = money.replace(m_trim, '', regex=True)

# or
money = money.str.replace(m_trim, '', regex=True)
```

Fix of your loop:

```
for i, m in money.items():
    money[i] = m_trim.sub('', m)
```

Or:

```
for i in money.index:
    money[i] = m_trim.sub('', money[i])
```

Output:

```
0     USDCNY
1    USDRCNY
Name: Сокращенное наименование , dtype: object
```